# How to say "invitation for war"?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

I want to say that my grandad got an invitation for war. I'm not even sure that the word "invitation" is okay in English. I mean he got a letter saying that he must join the army and fight for his country.

Can I say it like this:

> Mon grand-père a reçu une invitation à la guerre.

Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In French you wouldn't, in any case, say "invitation for war"; a proper term would be "avis d'appel sous les drapeaux"; (it might be "notice of call for military service" or "requisition letter to go to war" in English.)

- Mon grand-père a reçu un avis d'appel sous les drapeaux.

Another way to say that, but less literary

- Mon grand-père vient de recevoir une lettre de réquisition pour partir à la guerre.

Answer (score 5):

The expression *une invitation à la guerre* does exist in French, but it is a soften/unofficial version of *déclaration de guerre* and is usually not to be taken literally.

*Appel sous les drapeaux* is idiomatic but doesn't (necessarily) relate to war, just that you have to serve the army for a period of time.

When this relates to a starting war, the most idiomatic expression is:

> Mon grand-père a été mobilisé en xxxx

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the uncertainty expressed in your second sentence, rest assured that using the notion of getting an "invitation to [join the Army/become a soldier/fight a war]" to **euphemistically** characterize "being drafted" is perfectly okay in English (at least in American English, where the invitation is often described, as it is [here](https://www.rockdalenewtoncitizen.com/news/local/a-veteran-s-story-rutledge-farm-boy-a-survivor-of/article_63687bd8-c5a8-5e5d-8840-bf587d34f853.html) under the caption & in paragraph three, as having been issued by/received from "Uncle Sam."
 (from *rockdalenewtoncitizen.com*)

If you are trying to at least approach this euphemistic tone in French, although "appelé" is used officially (i.e., non-euphemistically) to describe matters of conscription in French (just as "called-up" is in English), "appeler" can include the notion of "invitation" (which is included in your English version) and therefore, I would nevertheless suggest something like the following:

> [Mon grand-père a été **appelé** à la
>   guerre](https://books.google.com/books?id=fbTxEZeA9BEC&pg=PA93&dq=%22%C3%A9t%C3%A9+appel%C3%A9+%C3%A0+la+guerre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw3afsxKXiAhULnOAKHVVcDgsQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20appel%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20la%20guerre%22&f=false)
>   (paraphrased from *Six ans de bonheur, d'angoisse et d'espérance*,
>   by Pierre Martin, via *Googlebooks*)